# post file null when i send formdata from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send image from jquery to php, but the $_FILES answer of php is null.
Someone can tell me where I'm wrong?

js file

```
$('form.cwd-add-photo').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var files = $('.cwd-add-photo input[name="cwd-img-upload"]').prop('files')[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("cwd_system_require","cwd_add_photo");;
        $.each(files, function(key, value) {
            formData.append('photo['+key+']', value);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin+'/cwd_call',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(item){
                console.log(item);
            },
        });

    });
```

php file

```
if(isset($_POST['cwd_system_require'])){
switch($_POST['cwd_system_require']){
    case 'cwd_add_photo':
            var_dump($_FILES);
            var_dump($_POST);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, it’s `$_FILES` …

Comment: @04FS  man rewrite error ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add 'enctype' to your form field:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - but why do you think this is the problem?  OP hasn't included any HTML at all...

Comment: That is the most common error a developer do while submitting a form with file input.